# DES encryption in PHP

Tags: php, drupal, encryption, des

I am coding a Drupal payment method module and within this I need to generate a hash to send to a bank. Bank asks me to code certain strings into the DES/ECB hash. They also provide test environment and here comes my problem. With the string B7DC02D5D6F2689E and key 7465737465703031 I should get result hash 3627C7356B25922B (after bin2hex, of course). This is by the bank test page and I have also checked this on this page: http://www.riscure.com/tech-corner/online-crypto-tools/des.html (encryption java applet).

My problem is that whatever I do I cant get my PHP code to provide the correct result. This is a simple function I am trying to use:

```
function encrypt($hash, $key)
{
$hash = strtoupper(substr(sha1($hash), 0, 16));
$key = strtoupper(bin2hex($key));

$block = mcrypt_get_block_size('des', 'ecb');
if (($pad = $block - (strlen($hash) % $block)) < $block) {
  $hash .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

$sig = strtoupper(bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $hash, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));
return $sig;
}
```

and I have been trying sth like this as well:

```
function encrypt( $value, $key) {
$hash = strtoupper(substr(sha1($value), 0, 16));
$key = strtoupper(substr(bin2hex($key), 0, 16));
// encrypt hash with key
if (function_exists('mcrypt_module_open')) {         // We have mcrypt 2.4.x
  $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_DES, "", MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, "");
  $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size ($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
  mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
  $signature = strtoupper(bin2hex(mcrypt_generic ($td, $hash)));
  mcrypt_generic_end ($td);
}
else
{                        // We have 2.2.x only
$signature = strtoupper(bin2hex(mcrypt_ecb (MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $hash, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT)));
}
return $signature;
}
```

None of these gave the correct signature. Any idea what's wrong? For now I am dealing with this issue more than 3 hrs, so I appreciate any help. I am not very familiar with this encryption stuff. Thanks a lot.

Btw.: Those $hash and $key mentioned above are after the strtoupper, substr and bin2hex functions at the beginning of my code snippets.

Comment: As a sideline, if this is for a bank, I strongly recommend TRIPLEDES over DES... DES is well known to be broken.

Comment: Not the OP's decision to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
function encrypt($hash, $key) {
    return mcrypt_encrypt("des", pack("H*", $key), pack("H*", $hash), "ecb");
}

print bin2hex(encrypt("B7DC02D5D6F2689E", "7465737465703031"));
```

This prints `3627c7356b25922b` for me, so it looks like that's working.

You were on the right track with `bin2hex()`, but that was converting in the wrong direction. (There's unfortunately no `hex2bin()` function, so you have to use `pack()` instead.)

You also don't need an IV for a single-block encryption like this.

Answer (score 0):

You plaintext, `B7DC02D5D6F2689E`, is 8 bytes = 64 bits.  This is an exact block for DES so you don't need any padding in ECB mode.  I suggest that you remove the padding code entirely.  All DEC-ECB needs in this case is the block to encrypt and the key; no padding and no IV.